# How to show XAML inside a Tab Control in Silverlight 4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0, tabcontrol

I am wondering how to display a XAML page within a tab control that is part of another XAML page.  Or, for that matter, if this is even possible.  I want to be able to click a button on page1 and be able to view the page2 from within a tab control that is on page1.

Would this be something to be handled within a Frame control? Or something different? Or is there a better approach to this altogether?

I am programming in Silverlight-4.0, C#-4.0 from within Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the navigation framework, but that isn't really what you're asking.  You want to know how to put the contents of one file into a tab, while the contents of another file are in the other tab.

A page in silverlight is simply a user control.  You can put a usercontrol into the tab just like you would any other control.  In order to use a local usercontrol in another xaml file, you'll need to do the following:

Add this to the root element of the page containing the tabs:

```
xmlns:local="clr-reference.MyApplicationNamespace"
```

Then you can add this to add the control into the tab:

```
<local:usercontrolname name="mycontrol" someproperty="value" />
```

Comment: Yes, I believe this is what I was wanting. Question though, after doing this, would this allow me to add more pages to the same tab in the same fashion?

Comment: Because you are just adding a usercontrol to your page, you can add as many as you want.  Think of it less as adding another page to your page, and more as adding a control to your page.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [Silverlight Navgition Framework](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-Silverlight-3-Navigation-Framework.aspx) You can show "frames" inside your control. It also support deep linking, which is the killer feature here..

[This is a very good intro](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/navigation-framework/) - by Tim Heuer